# MDX expression where dimension members become column totals

Tags: ssas, mdx, cube

I have data in a cube (SSAS 2014) that looks like this:

```
Dim1    Dim2    Dim3        Meas1
Alpha   Marco   Chicago     10
Alpha   Polo    Atlanta     15
Alpha   Marco   Chicago     17
Beta    Polo    New York    21
Beta    Marco   Atlanta     31
Beta    Polo    Chicago     41
```

How do I write a MDX query to get a result like this?

```
Dim1    Dim2    ChicagoTotl/AtlantaTotl/NewYorkTotl
Alpha   Marco       27     /    0      /    0
Alpha   Polo        0      /    15     /    0
Beta    Marco       0      /    31     /    0
Beta    Polo        41     /    0      /    21
                                            ---
                                            135
```

In the report Dim1 & Dim2 are going to be user selectable filters.

But how do I string Dim3 out as individual columns?

What does this MDX look like?  Do columns done in this style have a name?  What do you call me?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
WITH 
  MEMBER [Measures].[ChicagoTotal] AS 
    (
      [Measures].[Meas1]
     ,[Dim3].[Hierarchy].[Chicago]
    ) 
  MEMBER [Measures].[NewYorkTotal] AS 
    (
      [Measures].[Meas1]
     ,[Dim3].[Hierarchy].[New York]
    ) 
  MEMBER [Measures].[AtlantaTotal] AS 
    (
      [Measures].[Meas1]
     ,[Dim3].[Hierarchy].[Atlanta]
    ) 
SELECT 
  NON EMPTY 
    {
      [Measures].[ChicagoTotal]
     ,[Measures].[NewYorkTotal]
     ,[Measures].[AtlantaTotal]
    } ON 0
 ,NON EMPTY 
    [Dim1].[Hierarchy].MEMBERS * [Dim2].[Hierarchy].MEMBERS ON 1
FROM [YourCube];
```

Comment: That makes sense.  So I will have to use a literal list of measures I want as the columns?  I would have to do pretty much the same in an SQL query so I'm not surprised.  But the MSX can't figure out the values of my columns based on values of the one member?  Thanks. and I'll try this this weekend and get back to you.

Comment: @Steve if you want to name a measure ChicagoTotal then you need to create a measure called ChicagoTotal... same as in sql if you want a column called ThisColumn then you need to name a column ThisColumn. Yes in sql it could be possible to play with dynamic sql etc to make the naming of the columns dynamic: if you use OPENQUERY against a linked server then you can also make your mdx string dynamic.

Comment: @SouravA you been on holiday?

Comment: No mate. I wish. Have been really busy with project work...deadlines...meetings..Missed StackOverflow!

Comment: @SouravA I've missed you matey - glad you're back! You haven't missed much though - mdx wise just the usual: how do I Order this set? how do I use this mdx in a sql-server proc? All the same stuff.

Comment: Thanks mate..hope to be active very soon and fight hard with you for reps :)

Answer (score 1):

Assume aggregation type for Meas1 is Sum. Then the query will be something like this:

```
SELECT [Dim3].[Hier3].MEMBERS on 0,  
[Dim1].[Hier1].MEMBERS * [Dim2].[Hier2].MEMBERS on 1 
FROM [Cube] WHERE ([Measures].[Meas1])
```

This query will create columns automatically based on members in Dim3.Hier3.